# Weighted Graph with arbitrary start/end points

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

I have a few hundred nodes.
Each node has a value for how beneficial it is to visit it.
Each node has a set distance between some number of other nodes.  Travel is permitted in both ways along these edges. (Weighted bi-directional edges)
I can start at any node I desire.
I CAN revisit existing nodes, but only after 11 steps.
So in other words, I am looking for the cycle of at least 11 nodes which provides the highest Value/Distance ratio.

I am barely familiar enough with graph theory to know how to describe this problem, and not at all familiar enough to know how to solve it in any semi-efficient manner. I'm honestly not even sure thinking about this data as a graph is useful at all, or if I should be rephrasing this as a some other kind of problem (Combinatorics?)

If there exists algorithms to solve this kind of problem, or even just literature on similar problems I could study, I would love to be pointed in that direction.

Comment: The question as written appears to best suited to Math Exchange https://math.stackexchange.com/ It does not appear to be related to _programming_, debugging, or typical related tasks which are the focus of StackOverflow.

Comment: Without additional constraints, this is going to be a very hard problem to solve. So I suggest that you add all the information you have about the graph. For example, what are the minimum, maximum, and average [degree in the graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(graph_theory))?  What are the minimum, maximum, and average edge weights, and node values? Is the graph a [planar graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph)? What other information do you have about the graph?

Comment: This is all very good info, thankyou a bunch!   I had not realized it would be that difficult.   To answer your questions, I had planned on limiting the degree down to ~5, as the dataset itself has every node accessible from every other node, so I was going to only include the ~5 closest nodes.   Which would follow that it is not a Planar Graph at all.    I actually have multiple problems I was hoping to solve with similar but different constraints, but this gives me enough information to do my own research and learn about my options.

Comment: I do not know what that question about planar graphs has to do with this.  I think the more important question is whether or not it is metric.  If you have hundreds of nodes and the graph is not metric, solving this is going to be complicated and possibly too slow for your needs - do you have a performance requirement?

Answer (score 3):

This is a variation on the travelling salesman problem.

The TSP is a very hard problem to solve, even without the extra constraints you have here. There are various ways to get an approximate solution, fairly close to the optimum, in a reasonable amount of time. Generally this is some kind of 'find nearest or most valuable next point'. The details depend on the details of your input data. Would you be interested in approximate solutions, or do you insist on getting the optimum?

Here is an example of the kind of approximation algorithm you can use to get a quick and dirty feasible solution with a worthwhile value.  It assumes that your input graph is "metric" - meaning there are no shortcuts A to B is always shorter than A to C to B for all A,B,C.  Is your input like that?

- Select the 11 most valuable nodes
- Use the Dijkstra algorithm to find the shortest path between every pair of the 11 nodes.
- Create a new graph with just the 11 nodes and links between them costed with the Dijsktra path costs.
- Apply the metric approximation of the TSP algorithm to the 11 selected nodes.
- Map the the TSP path back on to the original graph.

Perhaps it would be easiest if you just posted your input somewhere and provide a link.  There are numerous sensible ways to format the input.  I prefer a space delimited text file - like this: https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder3/wiki/Sales

Comment: Although the TSP is an np-hard problem, there are exact solvers like [Concorde](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/tsp/concorde/index.html) which can knock this problem out of the park for even very large instances!. As for heuristics, OP can refer to [Google's routing solver](https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/tsp).